# Read Excel .CSV file in Powershell, use a variable from each column, and run a .exe with the variables

Tags: variables, powershell

I am quite new to Powershell, but I am trying to write what seems like a slightly complicated script.  What I am trying to do is read a phone number, a subject, and a file path from the .csv file, put those 3 things as variables, and then run a .exe with the variables.  This will be used so we can send faxes to our clients, and there are around 500 or so.  I am not sure if this is the easiest way or not to accomplish this with powershell, but the .exe is apparently ready, I just need to see if a powershell script will work in this scenario.

Currently, this is what I have come up with.

```
    $FaxNumber = @()
    $Subject = @()
    $FilePath = @()

    Import-Csv C:\Users\dlappert\Documents\Test\Book1.csv |`
        ForEach-Object {
            $FaxNumber += $_.FaxNumber
            $Subject += $_.Subject
        $FilePath += $_.FilePath
        }

    If ($_.FaxNumber -contains $InputNumber)
        {
        (*ExecutableFilePath*) /s(FaxServerIpAddress) /u /p /v /o C:\_.log1 /c NO COVER PAGE /r{$_.FaxNumber} /a {$_.FilePath} /b{$_.Subject}
        {
```

I would really appreciate any assistance that anyone could provide with this.  This script needs to read the first 3 columns, and execute the script for each row of information.  If there is an easier way to accomplish this, please let me know.

Comment: Does your script actually work? Your `If` statement is outside the pipeline, and you are using the `$_` variable in it... for what cause? And what do you mean by "easier way". If it works, then it is good. And what is the $InputNumber?

Comment: No, I cannot get it to work.  As I said, I am just a noob when it comes to this.  I am pretty much stuck right now and do not know which way to go.  If the entire code needs to be scrapped, that is fine with me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I see, you don't need the arrays...

```
Import-Csv C:\Users\dlappert\Documents\Test\Book1.csv |
foreach {
    Start-Process -FilePath "executable_path" -ArgumentList "/s(FaxServerIpAddress) /u /p /v /o C:\_.log1 /c NO COVER PAGE /r$($_.FaxNumber) /a `"$($_.FilePath)`" /b$($_.Subject)" 
}
```

Comment: I have tested this with some mock files but to no avail.  Just to re-iterate, I need this script to read a .csv file, plug the 3 columns into the .exe, and execute the .exe with the data from the 3 columns for each row in the .csv file.

I hope I have explained this clearly.

Comment: @user2459545 I have made some adjustments. It should work now.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I found an easier way to complete this without Powershell.  It seems if we do this with a batch file and convert the .csv file to a text file, it is much easier.  Thank you for your assistance though, as we did also get this to work, so if this is an operation that is needed in the future, the powershell script will be ready.  I appreciate your assistance Davor.